External Builder Script Sequence in Hyperledger Fabric
When using the external chaincode builder in Hyperledger Fabric, it can be confusing to understand the order in which various scripts (build, detect, release, etc.) are executed, and how they fit into the lifecycle of chaincode installation, approval, commit, and execution. Below is a detailed breakdown to help clarify this process.
Summary of the Script and Lifecycle Order
External Builder Script Execution:
detect
build
release
run
Chaincode Lifecycle Order:
Start the peer with external builder configured.
Install the chaincode (detect and build scripts invoked).
Approve the chaincode definition.
Commit the chaincode definition.
Execute chaincode (run script invoked).

If this information is missing from the documentation, it would be great to contribute updates to one (or both) of these sections: https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.5/cc_launcher.html, https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.5/cc_service.html. The source is located at https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/tree/main/docs

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
